# How to map dates range of relative dates coming from the same field in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, sql-view

I need to build an SQL view in Redshift:

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to get the following format:

[image]

The idea is to have, for each Date, the orders corresponding to Date - 5 days, orders corresponding to Date - 6 days, and orders corresponding to Date - 7 days.

I am struggling to find the solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What does "order of date2" mean?

Comment: I mean orders corresponding to the date2 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select date, lag(date, 5) over (order by date) as date2, lag(orders, 5) over (order by date) as orders
from t
union all
select date, lag(date, 6) over (order by date) as date2, lag(orders, 6) over (order by date) as orders
from t
union all
select date, lag(date, 7) over (order by date) as date2, lag(orders, 7) over (order by date) as orders
from t;
```